# Point Subdomain to Google Compute Project/VM over 443

Tags: dns, google-compute-engine

So here's the issue I'm trying to sort out:

I want to create a subdomain for a domain I own and point it to a Google Compute VM. The part that I'm having difficulty with is that I have set the VM to require traffic over 443, which obviously changes the connection URL to `https://IPADDRESS/`, and traffic coming from port 80 isn't being redirected on the Google side.

I had created the subdomain with an "A" record pointing to the IP, which didn't work. So, in short, how do I point traffic from `sub.customdomain.com` with my DNS registrar to the Google Compute VM public IP using `https://`?

Comment: How creating "A" record to poiting to IP address of your GCE VM instance didn't work? Usually it takes some time (a few hours at least) the change propagated.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to configure [Subdomain forwarding](https://support.google.com/domains/answer/6072198).

- configure common A record `httpsonly.customdomain.com` pointing to your instance IP address
- configure subdomain forwarding: create synthetic record `sub.customdomain.com` pointing to URL `https://httpsonly.customdomain.com`

This way any user hitting `sub.customdomain.com` will be redirected to  port 443 at your HTTPS-only instance.

Note that subdomain forwarding functionality might not be available at your domain registrar.